# MYSQL - Is there an alternative to LIMIT in subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm using **MYSQL**. I have the table bellow:

```
create table visit (
   id int,
   seller_number varchar(10),
   date_visit date,
   city_visited varchar(50),
   status varchar(50)
);
```

An example data for this table:

```
id   seller_number  date_visit    city_visited      status

10   11111          2005-02-12    Goiania/GO        Yes
11   11111          2010-05-19    Marilia/SP        Sim
12   11111          2015-01-23    Brasilia/DF       No
13   22222          2014-01-02    Brasilia/DF       Yes
14   22222          2012-10-21    Goiania/GO        No
15   33333          2010-08-09    Marilia/SP        No
```

I need a **SQL** that **returns only the row with the most current date of each seller**, like this:

```
id   seller_number  date_visit    city_visited      status

12   11111          2015-01-23    Brasilia/DF       No
13   22222          2014-01-02    Brasilia/DF       Yes
15   33333          2010-08-09    Marilia/SP        No
```

I am doing this using **subquery**, but **MYSQL did not accept the LIMIT**:

```
SELECT seller_number, date_visit, city_visited, status FROM visit WHERE (seller_number, date_visit) IN (SELECT seller_number, MAX(date_visit) FROM visit GROUP BY seller_number LIMIT 500);
```

**Without LIMIT it works**, but I need to limit it because the table has more than 30 million tuples and it is not possible to query.

**Is there any other alternative way to get this result without using LIMIT in the subquery?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use existential quantifier and a correlated subquery instead of picking the max date explicitly:

```
SELECT
    v.seller_number
,   v.date_visit
,   v.city_visited
,   v.status
FROM visit v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM visit otherVisit
    WHERE v.seller_number=otherVisit.seller_number
      AND otherVisit.date_visit > v.date_visit
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches in MySQL.  Your method is fine, but the `LIMIT` needs to go in the outer query:

```
SELECT v.seller_number, v.date_visit, v.city_visited, v.status
FROM visit v
WHERE (v.seller_number, v.date_visit) IN
       (SELECT v2.seller_number, MAX(v2.date_visit)
        FROM visit v2
        GROUP BY v2.seller_number
       )
LIMIT 500;
```